# Erro ao adicionar novas instâncias em um array em Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, instanciar-objeto, coffeescript

Estou com o seguinte problema tenho um array que adiciono a instância de um objeto auxiliar para a instância de um HTMLElement, mas apenas o último elemento está sendo adicionado, testei no navegador Chrome, Chromium, Opera e Mozilla Firefox e em nenhum deles apresentou um resultado diferente.

Esse é o código em CoffeeScript adicionando a instância no array:

```
array = []
if not isEmpty(results)
    for result in results
        element = new VanillaHTMLDOMElement(result)
        console.log(element.getAttribute('id')) ##imprime o id do elemento normalmente
        array.push(element)
for item in array
    console.log item.getAttribute('id') ##imprime nulo para todos os casos
return array
```

Esse é o código em Javascript adicionando a instância no array:

```
var array, element, item, result, _i, _j, _len, _len1;
array = [];
if (!isEmpty(results)) {
  for (_i = 0, _len = results.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    result = results[_i];
    element = new VanillaHTMLDOMElement(result);
    console.log(element.getAttribute('id')); //imprime o id do elemento normalmente 
    array.push(element);
  }
}
for (_j = 0, _len1 = array.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
  item = array[_j];
  console.log(item.getAttribute('id')); //imprime nulo para todos os casos
return array
}
return array;
```

Acredito que seja devido a alguma forma de Assincronismo, mas gostaria de confirma e gostaria de saber se alguém sabe alguma solução?

Comment: Eu não conheço muito de Vanilla, mas aparentemente não tem nada errado. Tentou criar objetos-padrão com o DOM e colocar no array para ver a saída?

Comment: Você tem o código da função `VanillaHTMLDOMElement`?

Comment: [Tentei reproduzir o problema](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQsE4/) mas não consegui.

Comment: Encontrei a solução, o problema de fato era na classe VanillaHTMLDOMElement. Aparentemente os atributos privados do CoffeeScript são ao mesmo tempo estáticos, isso fazia com que ao eu dar um new VanillaHTMLDOMElement(result) , todas as instâncias da classe VanillaHTMLDOMElement, apontassem para o último result. Obrigado pela ajuda de vocês.

Answer (score -1):

Em vez de:

```
array.push(element);
```

Tente utilizar:

```
array = [].push.apply(array, element);
```